# UITextField in UITableView tableFooterView bouncing up offscreen on resignFirstResponder

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, resignfirstresponder

I've searched and searched this problem and I admit I might be missing something, but I'm out of ideas.

I have a UITextField in a UITableView tableFooterView in my mainClass:

```
// Set table footer
PAPPhotoDetailsFooterView *footerView = [[PAPPhotoDetailsFooterView alloc] initWithFrame:[PAPPhotoDetailsFooterView rectForView]];
commentTextField = footerView.commentField;
commentTextField.delegate = self;
self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
```

The textField is setup in the PAPPhotoDetailsFooterView class like so:

```
 commentField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake( 25.0f, 10.0f, 227.0f, 31.0f)];
 commentField.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:kCommentCellContentLabelFontSize];
 commentField.placeholder = @"Name photo";
 commentField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeySend;
 commentField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
 commentField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
 commentField.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:73.0f/255.0f green:55.0f/255.0f blue:35.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
 commentField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
 [commentField setValue:[UIColor colorWithRed:154.0f/255.0f green:146.0f/255.0f blue:138.0f/255.0f alpha:1.0f] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"]; 
 [mainView addSubview:commentField];
```

Here's my textFieldShouldReturn method in my mainClass:

```
#pragma mark - UITextFieldDelegate
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {

    // Call method to store comment
    NSString *trimmedComment = [textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    [self parseAndStoreComment:trimmedComment];

    // Reset the text field
    [textField setText:@""];
    return  [textField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

And my keyboard methods:

```
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification*)note {
    // Scroll the view to the comment text box
    NSDictionary* info = [note userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;   
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, self.tableView.contentSize.height-kbSize.height) animated:YES];

}


- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)note {       
    [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0f, self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame.origin.y) animated:YES];
}
```

---

What's happening is when I click off the textField -OR- when I hit return on the keyboard, then the tableView seems to scroll to whatever I set in keyboardWillHide, but then immediately afterwards it will quickly scroll up to where the tableView is completely up and offscreen.

I tried setting the animation of `setContentOffset` to 2.0f seconds in `keyboardWillHide`, to see what happens, and this will cause the contentOffset I specify to scroll over 2 seconds, but then immediately afterwards it will shoot offscreen.

Something is scrolling the tableView after my code scrolls it but I have no idea what it is.

Answer (score 0):

So I've realized that this is only happening on the Simulator. I've been testing the app on both the simulator and device, but I guess every time I've tried to debug this issue I've only tested on the simulator.

Not sure why it's happening on the simulator.